# WPF DataGrid slow loading time

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, render

We're talking about up to two minutes to render a window. The window contains a DataGrid inside a Grid, hooked up to a DataTable with up to 1000 elements. 
I set up the DG's height and width manually, the Grid's row height is manually set as well, every column in the datagrid has manual width set.

It takes at most 300 ms to fetch the data from the DB and creating the datatable, but it takes a whole lot of time rendering it.

I tried Virtualization, the difference is very little, barely noticeable in the normal use of the program.

My question is why, if I set the height and width of everything, when I go into a diag session, it says "Changes were made to this element that required the size and/or position of this element to be computed". It takes up to 200 ms per DataGridRow, which I find to be rather slow.

I am using TemplateDataColumn because I actually need to use a textbox that extends the normal one.

Any ideas are more than welcome, I've been fighting this for about two weeks now and I'm running out of ideas.

We are running this on a server, I tried to get it to work locally but seeing how IBM doesn't seem to be able to build a setup that works in order for me to painlessly install the DB2 driver to set up the Windows DSN, I can't test it locally with a GPU to see if it would help the rendering process.

Thank you for your time and attention.

Edit: Added the datagrid code as per request.

While this DG is rather complex, the rendering time issue is not restricted to this one.

```
<av:DataGrid BorderThickness="0" Height="550"  x:Name="dgLineasPresupuesto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1125"
        SelectionChanged="Refresh" SelectionMode="Single" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" CanUserAddRows="False" PreviewKeyDown="MyPreviewKeyDown"
        AlternationCount="1" AlternatingRowBackground="#444D58" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="true" IsEnabled="True" GotFocus="dgPresupu_GotFocus"
        ItemsSource="{av:Binding}" EnableRowVirtualization="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" >
    <av:DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkGray"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
        <av:SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static av:SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#526885" />
        <av:Style TargetType="{x:Type av:DataGridCell}" x:Key="Celda" >
            <av:Style.Triggers>
                <av:Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <av:Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </av:Trigger>
            </av:Style.Triggers>
        </av:Style>
        <av:Style TargetType="{x:Type av:DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <av:Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <av:Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <av:Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />
            <av:Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </av:Style>
        <av:Style TargetType="{x:Type av:TextBox}">
            <av:Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <av:Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <av:Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </av:Style>
        <av:Style TargetType="{x:Type jaime:TextBoxNum}">
            <av:Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <av:Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <av:Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </av:Style>
        <av:Style TargetType="{x:Type andrei:TextBoxFecha}">
            <av:Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <av:Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <av:Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </av:Style>
        <av:Style TargetType="{x:Type av:CheckBox}">
            <av:Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <av:Setter Property="Background" Value="white"/>
            <av:Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </av:Style>
    </av:DataGrid.Resources>
    <av:DataGrid.Background>
        <av:StaticResource ResourceKey="tertiary_Dark"/>
    </av:DataGrid.Background>
    <av:DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
        <av:StaticResource ResourceKey="text_dark"/>
    </av:DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
    <av:DataGrid.RowBackground>
        <av:StaticResource ResourceKey="tertiary_Dark"/>
    </av:DataGrid.RowBackground>
    <av:DataGrid.Foreground>
        <av:StaticResource ResourceKey="text_dark"/>
    </av:DataGrid.Foreground>
    <av:DataGrid.Columns>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="CodProp" Header=""
                Width="20">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <av:TextBox TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="20">
                        <av:TextBox.Style>
                            <av:Style TargetType="{x:Type av:TextBox}">
                                <av:Style.Triggers>
                                    <av:DataTrigger Value="">
                                        <av:DataTrigger.Binding>
                                            <av:MultiBinding
                                                    Converter="{av:StaticResource SemaforosConverterLinPres}">
                                                <av:Binding Path="RevLinLPre" />
                                                <av:Binding Path="UsuRevLPre" />
                                            </av:MultiBinding>
                                        </av:DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <av:Setter Property="Background"
                                                Value="Transparent" />
                                    </av:DataTrigger>
                                    <av:DataTrigger Value="Ambar">
                                        <av:DataTrigger.Binding>
                                            <av:MultiBinding
                                                    Converter="{av:StaticResource SemaforosConverterLinPres}">
                                                <av:Binding Path="RevLinLPre" />
                                                <av:Binding Path="UsuRevLPre" />
                                            </av:MultiBinding>
                                        </av:DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <av:Setter Property="Background"
                                                Value="{av:StaticResource semaforoIosAmarillo}" />
                                        <av:Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Genérico"/>
                                    </av:DataTrigger>
                                    <av:DataTrigger Value="Rojo">
                                        <av:DataTrigger.Binding>
                                            <av:MultiBinding
                                                    Converter="{av:StaticResource SemaforosConverterLinPres}">
                                                <av:Binding Path="RevLinLPre" />
                                                <av:Binding Path="UsuRevLPre" />
                                            </av:MultiBinding>
                                        </av:DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <av:Setter Property="Background"
                                                Value="{av:StaticResource semaforoIosRojo}" />
                                        <av:Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Obsoleto"/>
                                    </av:DataTrigger>
                                </av:Style.Triggers>
                            </av:Style>
                        </av:TextBox.Style>
                    </av:TextBox>
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Lin"
                Width="60" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <jaime:TextBoxNum Text="{av:Binding LinPre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Artículo"
                Width="145" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <av:TextBox Text="{av:Binding CodArtPre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"
                            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Cantidad"
                Width="100" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <jaime:TextBoxNum Text="{av:Binding CanLPre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="{av:Binding EditItem}"
                            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" PreviewKeyDown="dgLinPres_previewKeyDown"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" x:Name="CanLPre" LostFocus="linprelostfocus" GotFocus="tx_gotFocus"/>
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Precio"
                Width="100" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <jaime:TextBoxNum NumDec="2"  Text="{av:Binding PrePre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="{av:Binding EditItem}"
                            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" PreviewKeyDown="dgLinPres_previewKeyDown"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" x:Name="PrePre" LostFocus="linprelostfocus" GotFocus="tx_gotFocus" TextChanged="tb_Change" />
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Uds./Pre."
                Width="80" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <jaime:TextBoxNum Text="{av:Binding UdsPre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="{av:Binding EditItem}"
                            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" PreviewKeyDown="dgLinPres_previewKeyDown"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" x:Name="UdsPre" LostFocus="linprelostfocus" GotFocus="tx_gotFocus"/>
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Dto1"
                Width="80" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <jaime:TextBoxNum NumDec="2"  Desc="True" Text="{av:Binding Dto1LPre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="{av:Binding EditItem}"
                            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" PreviewKeyDown="dgLinPres_previewKeyDown"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" x:Name="Dto1LPre" LostFocus="linprelostfocus" GotFocus="tx_gotFocus" TextChanged="tb_Change"/>
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Dto2"
                Width="80" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <jaime:TextBoxNum NumDec="2"  Desc="True" Text="{av:Binding Dto2LPre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="{av:Binding EditItem}"
                            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" PreviewKeyDown="dgLinPres_previewKeyDown"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" x:Name="Dto2LPre" LostFocus="linprelostfocus" GotFocus="tx_gotFocus" TextChanged="tb_Change"/>
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Dto3"
                Width="80" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <jaime:TextBoxNum NumDec="2"  Desc="True" Text="{av:Binding Dto3LPre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="{av:Binding EditItem}"
                            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" PreviewKeyDown="dgLinPres_previewKeyDown"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" x:Name="Dto3LPre" LostFocus="linprelostfocus" GotFocus="tx_gotFocus" TextChanged="tb_Change"/>
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="" Header="Importe"
                Width="100" CellStyle="{av:StaticResource Celda}">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <av:TextBox Text="{av:Binding ImpLPre}" TextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"
                            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="P" Width="60">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <av:CheckBox
                            IsChecked="{av:Binding ConProLPre, Converter={av:StaticResource CheckboxConverter}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="U" Width="60">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <av:CheckBox IsChecked="{av:Binding ConUsrLPre, Converter={av:StaticResource CheckboxConverter}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="N" Width="60">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <av:CheckBox
                            IsChecked="{av:Binding NetLPre, Converter={av:StaticResource CheckboxConverter}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"  Checked="checkNeto" Unchecked="uncheckNeto"/>
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="E" Width="60">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <av:CheckBox                                                       
                            IsChecked="{av:Binding EspLPre, Converter={av:StaticResource CheckboxConverter}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="checkExpecial" Unchecked="uncheckEspecial"/>
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <av:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="R" Width="60">
            <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <av:DataTemplate>
                    <av:CheckBox                                                       
                            IsChecked="{av:Binding RevLinLPre, Converter={av:StaticResource CheckboxConverter}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </av:DataTemplate>
            </av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </av:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </av:DataGrid.Columns>
</av:DataGrid>
```

Comment: provide context in the form of code please

Comment: have you tried out any profiling tools yet?

Comment: I see everything is coming from the "av" namespace, does this `DataGrid` come from a 3rd party library?

Comment: To me this sounds like a virtualization issue, since you are positive that the fetching of data is done in a reasonable amount of time. In your DataGrid `EnableRowVirtualization` and  `EnableColumnVirtualization` are both set to `False`. This effectively disables virtualization. Try to place a standard DataGrid, set both those properties to `True` and bind to your data source. See if you still have that issue.

Comment: @BradleyUffner the av namespace was added by a coworker, it is efectively pointing to xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", idk why he added it, but it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @r41n as I said in the post, enabling virtualization gives me some bugs that I have to figure out when processing the events, but enabling them doesn't really impact the loading time. I tried binding the datasource but it's not showing the elements unless I do a Refresh afterwards, so I'm on it now.

Comment: @Dbl I did profile it with the visual studio profiler, and as I said, most of the time it's in the drawing with the message "Changes were made to this element that required the size and/or position of this element to be computed".

Comment: @ManuAndrei I was talking about an external profiler. Try a demo from redgate/jetbrains (Both offer trials and they're really worth the money if you regularly develop with c#). Those helped me loads finding such issues because they will precisely tell you which method is causing all the workload. Though to be honest i overread your diag session statement